# in django template unable to show content inside if block

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

when i write if statement nothing show in html but when i remove the  if statement the code show all items what is wrong

```
  {% for catagory in catagory_list %}
      {% for item in product_list %}
           {% if item.catagory == "Fruits" %}     
                <p>{{item.catagory}}</p>
                <p>{{item.name}}</p>
                <p>{{item.price}}</p>
                <img src="{{item.image.url}}" alt="">
           {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are there any items with the catagory of "Fruits" and does the way you've written Fruits match it. For example are you using choices to defince categories in your model, what is the other option in the list, try that. Really need more code here. Could you show the model for the item as well, specifically how you have define the catagory on it. Also your naming is confusing, are u sure u aren't already filtering items in your view,  may also be another reason why u don't need the if. But without seeing how you generate the context no one can help you.

Comment: well then the if doesn't trigger... we can't say more with the information provided

Comment: PS it's spelt category.

Comment: Please share the context from your views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because catagory is an Object, Try:

```
{% if item.catagory.name == "Fruits" %}
```

assuming that catagory model has an attribute "name"